# convert date from json's responce

Tags: json, date

I have following code. I get {{createDate}} and {{expDate}} in the following format "2013-07-16T00:00:00". How can I convert them in format like this: 2013-07-16

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#domainName').typeahead({
            limit: 5,
            remote:{
                url: '/rest/search/domains',
                filter: function(parsedResponse) {
                    return parsedResponse.data;
                }
            },
            prefetch: '/rest/search/domains',
            template: [
                '<p class="repo-language"><span class="">',
                '</span> <strong>{{domainName}}</strong><span class="pull-right label label-success">Paid</span></p>',
                '<p class="repo-name"><small>{{userName}} / {{userEmail}}</small></p>',
                '<p class="repo-description"><small class="text text-success">Create Date: {{createDate}}</small></p>'+
                '<p class="repo-description"><small class="text text-danger">Expire Date: {{expireDate}}</small></p>'
            ].join(''),
            engine: Hogan
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
            console.log(datum);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in javascript.

```
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy; document.getElementById("DATE").value = today;
```

Check this out:

```
var from = "2013-07-16T00:00:00"; 
date = from.split("T");
alert(date[0]); //gives 2013-07-16
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/72Kxu/) is a working example

Hope this helps

Comment: I need get date from db.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example, do a simple split on the data you obtain.